# is it safe to ask for a location in didExit or didEnterRegion?

Tags: ios, core-location, clregion

I am using region monitoring in one of my apps. I am wondering.. is it save to ask location manager for a current location when didExitRegion or didEnterRegion is called?  Like this:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
        let currnetLocation = manager.location
    }
```

This happens when the app is suspended and launched in the background. Logic tells me that the `location` property should not be `nil` when the app exits or enters a region, because the system knows it isn't in the specified region anymore. Still I do not know what ios does under the hood. So the question is, is it safe to ask for a location when entering or exiting a region?

Comment: The location is independent of any region. Location is unlikely to be nil since the system needs to know where it is in order to determine if it is inside or outside the region.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. Still I couldn't tell 100% if the location property is set at the time didEnterRegion is called, because there is a cloud of mystery around core location.

Comment: There isn't much mystery as such, it is dependent on real-world data so there may be bad GPS signal etc, but as I said, if the device was able to determine that it is in a region then it must know where it is